# How to avoid duplicate documents in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am trying to index hbase data using MapReduceindexer Tool. I am successfully indexing using below command

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase-solr/tools/hbase-indexer-mr-1.5-cdh5.3.0-job.jar  --hbase-indexer-zk localhost --hbase-table-name indexdemo-user --hbase-indexer-name mynewindexer  --hbase-indexer-file /home/cloudera/indexdemo-indexer.xml   --collection collection1 --go-live
```

Above command successfully indexed the data ,I am able to see from solr Web UI also.But when I run the above command second time ,again it is indexing the same and showing two documents in solr UI.But my requiurement is to have a single document(i.e second run has to overwrite the first one's data).So that even if I run the same command multiple times,I will have to get only one doc with latest entries.(Note : When I index directly using java API,even if run the same program multiple times ,It is giving only one document .Same thing I need using the indexer tool)

Any suggestions are appreciated..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @prasad did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Define the field that has the unique value that identifies the document as [the uniqueKey for the schema](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Schema+Elements). As long as the uniqueKey is identical across each run, the old documents will be replaced / updated.

If you're however generating a unique value each time you're indexing (or haven't configured the uniqueKey), Solr will have no way to tell which documents really are the same document.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh ,thanks for your reply.I already have defined 'id' as unique key.In normal ingestion through java API, it is  functioning good.But when I run mapreduce indexer tool, its not working

Comment: Have you checked what the values for the `id` field actually is (for the duplicated documents and their original version) after your import?

Comment: yes @MatsLindh ,I checked ,it is same .see following is the output "response": {
    "numFound": 4,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "4480",
        "name": "baapuji",
        "_version_": 1506581334692200400
      },
      {
        "id": "4450",
        "name": "rajaa",
        "_version_": 1506581334689054700
      },
      {
        "id": "4480",
        "name": "baapuji",
        "_version_": 1506581462491594800
      },
      {
        "id": "4450",
        "name": "rajaa",
        "_version_": 1506581462503129000
      }
    ]